# Scrape multilevel menu using Scrapy 1.5

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get all links from multilevel menu.
start_urls = ['https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/category/ingredients']

```
import scrapy

from foodisgood.items import FoodisgoodItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst


class BbcSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'bbc'
    allowed_domains = ['bbcgoodfood.com']

    start_urls = ['https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/category/ingredients']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/recipes/category/[\w-]+$'), restrict_xpaths='//article[contains(@class, "cleargridindent")]'), callback='parse_sub_categories', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/recipes/collection/[\w-]+$'), restrict_xpaths='//article[contains(@class, "cleargridindent")]'), callback='parse_collections', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_sub_categories(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=FoodisgoodItem(), response=response)

        l.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

        l.add_xpath('category_title', '//h1[@class="section-head--title"]/text()')
        l.add_value('page_url', response.url)

        yield l.load_item()

    def parse_collections(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=FoodisgoodItem(), response=response)

        l.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

        l.add_xpath('collection_title', '//h1[@class="section-head--title"]/text()')
        l.add_value('page_url', response.url)

        yield l.load_item()
```

[Results of menu scraping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/738z6.png)
But I cant understand how populate empty first column before collection title.

For now I have:

EMPTY | Steak recipes |       https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/collection/steak

But I need:

Meat | Steak recipes |    https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/collection/steak

Can somebody give me advise what need to do to get result with subcategory in first column?

Thanks to everyone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not really doable using a `CrawlSpider`'s rules (at least not in a simple way).

The usual way to do this is documented in [Passing additional data to callback functions](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments).
You would extract the category in your first callback, and then create a new request passing this information in the `meta` dict.

Comment: Thank you for help) I use meta in requests, but here I try to use Rule. I dont understand where I need to pass meta. Can you give some code example.

Comment: Unfortunately, your callback and the rule's request creation are completely separated, so you can't do this using rules (at least without overwriting `CrawlSpider`'s private methods). You will have to find links and generate requests manually (just like shown in the linked docs)